# Spring boot with YAML, CORS doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, cors, yaml

is it possible to create YAML config to handle CORS? I use gradle and spring boot ver 1.5.4.
this is my YML file and it doesn't work:

```
 endpoints:
  cors:
    allowed-methods: '*'
    allowed-origins: '*'
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
       springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Anyone have idea what is wrong? thanks in advance for help

Comment: Are you using Spring Security as well?  It isn't widely known, but there is actually two versions of CORS, one within Security and the other in MVC.  I would make sure you explicitly disable CORS in security, as this looks like its using the MVC CORS support.

Comment: For now I'm not using spring security, update post above

Comment: Well, that doesn't mean spring boot starter web isn't setting it up for you regardless.  Figure out if it is being included in your dependency chain, it probably is with that dependency.  If you do find it in your chain https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#javaconfig and http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html with just disabling cors.